# Grunt: Phaser isn't Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower, phaser-framework

I am building a game in Phaser and using the Phaser Isometric plugin. I am also using grunt/bower/yeoman. I've taken the Isometric plugin source .js file and included it locally, as bower won't install it.

Anyway, whenever I run `grunt`, I'm given errors saying that Phaser is not defined in both the Isometric plugin source file and my main game file. I have installed Phaser through bower and it shows up in both the `bower_components` directory and, when I run `grunt serve`, in my main HTML doc. It's included in the HTML file and in the dependencies, yet grunt says that Phaser isn't defined. Because of this, the Phaser Isometric plugin is unusable because it has so many `'Phaser' is not defined` errors that it stops scanning the file, thus crashing the page.

Why is this error occurring, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What happened was actually a JSHint error. Since the variable Phaser wasn't defined in its main JS file, JSHint threw an error every time it was used, causing it to stop scanning. We just had to tell JSHint to ignore the entire file and it worked out fine.

Comment: You can add ignore option to `.jshintrc` in project root: `"globals": {"Phaser": false}`

Comment: Apizzimenti, if you answer and accept your question i think it could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been nearly two years (to the day) since I commented my solution, but it's worthy to finally respond.

As I mentioned in a comment above, we were using JSHint to lint our code. We accidentally included `node_modules` in the paths to be linted, and so an undefined variable *inside Phaser itself* was throwing out hundreds of errors, forcing JSHint and Grunt to stop scanning. Ignoring `node_modules` was a simple solution.

We've since moved on to different build tools, but this error might pop up again if anyone is using a similar linting setup.